# So can someone explain how to bake textures/normals?

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

I tried baking textures, it turns out this way and I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, so did you succeed? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yea i managed to do it, ive been doing the same thing over and over and every time it gave me different result. not sure what was up with that but i managed to do it. Thanks either way. :)